Why do we carve pumpkins on Halloween?
A Halloween tradition in the U.S. as well as other parts of the world is to carve pumpkins.
I have seen the folklore connected to this practice in the mention of Stingy Jack. But is that the only folklore connected to this tradition?
Is it connected to the pagan rituals of this holiday?
I have looked at the Wikipedia articles mentioned and I do not believe the sufficiently address my question. I do believe this question is properly scoped for the site as well has has value in its possible answer.

What research have you done?  What do you want to know beyond the information in Wikipedia?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack-o%27-lantern

I have made edits
